# Having a fixed mean of normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a substitute of `np.random.normal()`? I am seeking a function which will provide me a fixed `mean` and not vary with every run as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 50, 1.0 # mean and standard deviation
Nodes=220
r = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, Nodes)
print(r)

mean=np.mean(r)
print("mean =",mean)
```

Run 1 gives

```
mean = 49.957893448684665
```

Run 2 gives

```
mean = 50.13868428629214
```

Comment: Doesn't it kinda defeat the purpose of generating *random* numbers in the first place?

Comment: Use a seed: `np.random.seed(0)`

Comment: @matszwecja for scientific purposes it is quite nice to have something reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a seed to make the random numbers 'predictable'. This way you fix your random numbers and the mean will stay the same each time you run it. Even better, for everyone, the mean is now the same:

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 50, 1.0 # mean and standard deviation
Nodes=220

np.random.seed(0)

r = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, Nodes)
mean=np.mean(r)
print("mean =",mean)
```

Returns: `50.07519566707803`

Changing the value (seed value `0` in this case) will change your results